# how to share volumes with samba

Tags: networking, server, samba, proxy, nginx

I would like some help to configure 2 samba server in a specific way (never did that before)

I have a php script which send a file to a nginx load balanced cluster.  i'd like a shared volume between 2 servers behind the nginx so that when users access the url of the file, they never end up on a 404 error if the proxy pass redirect to the wrong serv.

Thank you